# How to make dynamic snow in the BGE?

Tags: python, game-engine, particles, logic-bricks

I want to make a scene in my game where the weather is controlled by some game properties (eg. Sunny=0, Rainy=1, Snowy=2, etc.) and I need a viable method for the game engine making snow on the fly.

I was originally going to use a snow-textured model that would fade in and out of the scene during times it would snow, to simulate buildup, but I then realized that I would have to rebuild the mesh I would use for that every time I edit the scene I wanted it in (which I do often).  I have seen several instances of tutorials that use snow in the Internal Renderer or Cycles, but that usually involves some sort of particle system setup, which isn't available in the BGE; and other examples that I have found that don't use particles, like their particle-heavy counterparts, are too taxing for a video game.

If there is a way I can create a system for snow without using my backup method, I would be very grateful.

Comment: You can do a mixture of different methods. E.g. particles (BGE particles) and planes with transparencies and environment effects (= snow on the ground). It does not need to be realistic. It needs to be plausible.